# Show that $ f: A \subset C \rightarrow C$ is continuous if and only if $z_n \rightarrow z_0$ in A implies that $f(z_n) \rightarrow f(z_0)$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I´m having a lot of problemas with continuity and my teacher ask me to do this exercise but I don´t know where to begin. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

We will use contrapositive to prove '$\Leftarrow$' ie $\neg(i)\implies \neg(ii)$. Suppose $f$ is not continuous. Then by definition $\exists \:\epsilon\: >0,\forall \:\delta >0 \: \text{such that }\:\exists \:z_1 \in A \:|z_1-c|<\delta \:\text{and}\: |f(z_1)-f(c)|\ge \: \epsilon$. This would mean $\exists \:\text{a sequence}\:\{z_n\}\subset A, z_n \to c$ and $\exists\:\epsilon_1 >0, \forall N\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\exists N_0\in \mathbb{N}\ni |f(z_{N_0})-f(c)|\ge \: \epsilon_1$. Indeed for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, set $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$. Then we have $\neg (ii)$. The converse is easy and you should be able to prove it.